# Why does this API request script fail at exactly 100 requests?

Tags: powershell, rest

I have written the below script (specific values omitted for security) which integrates with the API of a product and iterates through items discovered during the first request, performs a further request for each and adds their details to a JSON file.

The script works fine when it's a small number of items and does the job as expected, no issues with the functionality or logic.

However, as soon as the script hits **precisely 100 requests** (including the authentication request and initial `$GetHostsResult` part), I get the following error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: an unexpected error occurred on a send.

This happens when reaching the `Invoke-RestMethod` within the For Loop.

The vendor of the API states in their documentation that there are no limits with the exception of a timeout on the API key, which I have set well above the length of time the script would take to execute. I even tried to add a workaround to refresh the token before 100 requests happens, but to no avail.

I can only assume this is some kind of PowerShell issue.

Most importantly, if I stop the script and start it again immediately, it runs another 100 requests with no issue. From a Wireshark trace, I can see that the machine executing the script sends a reset, however as it's TLS encrypted, I am unable to drill down into that request.

There are no errors in the vendor's logs.

I am at a loss as to what is causing this. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
#Disable certificate validation and enforce TLS 1.2

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true};

#Set request variables
$BaseUri = '...';
$LoginUri = "$BaseUri/api/login";
$GetHostsUri = "$BaseUri/api/hosts";
$Headers = $null;

function SetHeaders {
    $script:Headers = @{
        'Authorization' = $Token
        'Accept' = 'application/hal+json'
    };    
}

$HostFields = '...';

$LoginForm = @{
    username = '...'
    password = '...'
}

#Set JSON variables
$JsonFilePath = '...'; 
$JsonFileName = '...'; 
$JsonFile = "$JsonFilePath$JsonFileName";


$response = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you wish to continue? (Y/N)"

if($response -eq "Y") {

    #Create file if required
    If ((Test-Path $JsonFile) -eq $False) {
        New-Item -Path $JsonFilePath -Name $JsonFileName -ItemType File;
    }

    #Create JSON array and host ArrayList
    $Json = @{};
    $HostList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    function GetAPIKey {
        #Log in to and get API key
        Write-Host "Retrievng API key..."
        $LoginResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $LoginUri -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Method POST -Body $LoginForm;
        $script:Token = $LoginResult;
        SetHeaders;
    }

    GetAPIKey;

    #Write-Host $Token;

    #Get all hosts in policy...
    Write-Host "Retrieving host list from policy..."
    $GetHostsResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetHostsUri -Method get -Headers $Headers -Body @{'matchRuleId' = '...'};
    Write-Host $GetHostsResult.hosts.Count "hosts found.";

    #Loop through each found host and request further host details, then add to ArrayList
    
    foreach ($element in $GetHostsResult.hosts) {
        $CurrentIndex = $GetHostsResult.hosts.IndexOf($element);

        Write-Host "Querying host" $CurrentIndex "- IP:" $element.ip"...";
        #Write-Host $Token;
        $GetHostResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($BaseUri + "/api/hosts/ip/" + $element.ip + "?fields=" + $HostFields) -Method get -Headers $Headers; 
    
        $HostList.Add($GetHostResult.host) > $null;
    }
    
    #Save array to JSON file
    Write-Host "Creating JSON file at $JsonFile";
    $Json.Add("Hosts",$HostList);
    $Json | ConvertTo-Json -depth 10 | out-file $JsonFile;

}
```

Comment: If you run a tool like Fiddler (which is basically a HTTP proxy with logging) it will insert a man-in-the-middle certificate and let you view the HTTPS traffic. Might not help, but it might show you something WireShark isn't...

Comment: What happens if you make the 100th request *first* (or at least straight after authenticating)? Is the server blowing up trying to process that request's specific details and it just happens to be the 100th request? What happens if you send 100 authentication requests (or the same *working* request 100x) - does it still blow up on request #100?

Comment: Thanks. Frustratingly, this is a customer's system I'm working on and the box I'm using doesn't have Fiddler installed. Good shout either way. As for your second comment, all requests fail from this point onwards, so it's not specifically the 100th request. I will try with a different set of data and see if that makes a difference but I'm hesitant.

Comment: No worries. There's apparently a portable version of Fiddler that just needs unzipping rather than installing if that helps any. And just to clarify, do you mean it looks like a specific poison request that breaks the session regardless of the position it's sent in? I.e. if you send your poison record in, say, position #10 then request #11 onwards will fail?

Comment: Thanks. No, I don't think so, it seems like it's a hard stop at 100 requests regardless of what they are. I've tried with a different set of data and it does the same thing unfortunately. It's almost like I'm hitting some kind of session limit.. perhaps PowerShell isn't closing the sessions down after making the requests and it's maxing out somewhere, but not knowing the technicalities of PowerShell, it's hard for me to pin that down.